# ASP.NET MVC Keep ModelState Valid on Failed Property Binding

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I'm wondering if there is any built in way in ASP.NET MVC to have a model property that is included in binding, but that doesn't invalidate the model if binding fails. Say I have the following simplified model that supports JqGrid CRUD operations:

```
public class JqGridCRUDDTO
{
    public JqGridCRUDOperation oper {get; set;}
    public int? id {get;set;}
}
```

When the model represents an "add" operation (specified by the `oper` property), JqGrid posts the id attribute of the containing HTML element as `id` (I believe that's what it is). In this case, binding for the id property fails which invalidates the `ModelState`. But the binding of the `id` property should only fail when I don't need it (I would only need a record id for "edit" and "delete" operations).

I realize that, ideally, I should have a separate model for each operation, but JqGrid seems to be more naturally suited to sending all CRUD operations to a single URL, so I'm not sure the separate model approach will lead to the simplest solution. The same goes for modifying my client side script such that JqGrid send an integer value when adding--I know it's possible, but it would add complexity to the client script. I'd prefer to manage as much complexity on the server side as possible.

If there's no built in way to do what I'm asking for, I'd like to hear how others would approach this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I full understand your problem. If you don't want that jqGrid send `id="_empty"` in case of Add operation you can just modify the value inside of `serializeEditData` or inside of `onclickSubmit`.

The first way (`onclickSubmit`):

```js
onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
    if (postdata[this.id + "_id"] === "_empty") {
        return {id: null};
    }
}
```

*Alternative* way (`serializeEditData`) don't save any `id` at all in case of Add operation:

```js
serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
    var data = $.extend({}, postdata); // make copy of postdata object
    if (data.id === "_empty") {
        delete data.id;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen other questions and answers that suggest I should be getting "_empty" when adding, but I'm actually getting "jqg1".

Comment: @grin0048: Probably you use inline editing using `inlineNav` or you calls `addRow` method directly (or probably you tse ``formatter: "actions"). In the case you can specify `rowID` parameter of `addRow` as a function which returns `null` or you can use `serializeRowData` callback which remove `id` value which value start with "jqg" (`$.jgrid.uidPref`). In any way if you would have implementation problems you should append the text of your question with Javascript code which shows how you use row editing and Add operation especially.

Comment: I was able to remove the `Id` parameter in serializeRowData. Thanks.